# Ubuntu 20.04 application menu lost all apps. Frequently used button gives crash

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, appmenu

I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on my dual boot. It was working well until all desktop icons in the application menu disappeared. The apps are still usable via command line or favourites, but gnome menu doesn't show anything. Searching for a specific app doesn't work either. Also, when I try to switch from All to frequent, the menu crashes and desktop refreshes itself. I looked around and found someone experienced a similar thing on Arch Linux with gnome, and a few things like reinstalling gnome-core or changing the format settings to a different country, but none solved it.

Edit: Here is a list of all apt files I have, since I was installing in batches I don't know exactly when the menu first broke:

chrome-gnome-shell
clamav-daemon
debfoster
firefox-locale-en
fonts-powerline
gir1.2-unity-5.0
git
gnome-tweaks
keepassxc
language-pack-gnome-en
linux-generic-hwe-20.04 
mtools
neofetch
neovim
shim-signed
tlp
ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-standard
ucaresystem-core
vlc
wbritish

Comment: *When* did the items disappear? Do you remember making any kind change to yours system before just that (e.g. installing an application or extension, changing system settings, changing theme etc.)?

Comment: @pomsky I added a list of files that I installed. Since I was setting a fresh install, I was installing many things at once, so I am not sure. I changed the theme to Yaru dark but it was still working when I did that.

Comment: I have similar issue. My apps are there but I see only first page and I cannot scroll the list... Searching for particular app works well. I am on fresh install done yesterday.

Comment: @pomsky I have caffeine, disconnect wifi, Hide activities button, Lock keys, openweather, Panel OSD, places status indicator, user themes.

Comment: Could you please try disabling *all* the extensions, then rebooting and see if that helps?

Comment: @pomsky It worked! Then I started checking which one, and turns out there was one more non-default extension which is called appfolder manager. That seemed to be the problematic one. Thanks for the help!